# Show that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over Q.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over Q. The hint is to show $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over F2, which is a finite field with two elements. I understand how to show $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over F2. However, I don't know how to use it to show $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over Q.

Comment: If it were reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it would be reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ (by Gauss’s Lemma), and the factorization over $\mathbb{Z}$ would yield a factorization over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: This is the $5$th cyclotomic polynomial. Hint: for every prime $p$, show that $\varphi_p(x+1)$ is irreducible using Eisenstein's criterion where $\varphi_p(x)$ is the $p-$th cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: You have to enclose the MathJax in `$` signs for the formatting to take effect

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** A monic polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ if and only if it is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.

**Hint 2** If $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=P(x)Q(x)$ for some $P,Q \in \mathbb Z[X]$ then 
$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \equiv P(x)Q(x) \pmod{2}$$

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the second hint